# Render new form if params are empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a video upload form. It works well when a video is chosen from the computer and submitted. The video gets uploaded. But if a user clicks on the submit button without selecting a video, it throws the following error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in VideosController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: video
```

What am I doing wrong here?

This is my video controller:

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_userinfo
    before_action :find_video, only: [:destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]

    def index
    end

    def new
        @video = Video.new
    end

    def create
        @video = Video.new(video_params)
        @video.userinfo_id = @userinformation.id
        @video.user_id = current_user.id


        if @video.save
            redirect_to userinfo_path(@userinformation)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
        @video.destroy
        redirect_to userinfo_path(@userinformation)
    end

    private
        def video_params
            params.require(:video).permit(:introvideo)
        end

        def find_userinfo
            @userinformation = Userinfo.friendly.find(params[:userinfo_id])
        end

        def find_video
            @video = Video.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

My form view:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@userinformation, @userinformation.videos.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :introvideo%>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Upload video'%>
<% end %>
```

I tried adding the following code to my controller but still didn't work:

```
def create
    @video = Video.new(video_params)
    @video.userinfo_id = @userinformation.id
    @video.user_id = current_user.id

    if @video.video_params.empty?
        render 'new'
    end

    if @video.save
        redirect_to userinfo_path(@userinformation)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa edited the question

Answer (score 1):

To properly check if `video` is empty you could do this:

```
def create
    return render 'new' if params[:video].blank?

    @video = Video.new(video_params)
    @video.userinfo_id = @userinformation.id
    @video.user_id = current_user.id

    if @video.save
        redirect_to userinfo_path(@userinformation)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey Gerry, thanks for answering. But I get the same  error. Maybe I'm entering the code wrong. I updated the last portion of  my question with the code I added, does that look right to you?

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner Ohh,  actually `@video.video_params.empty?` is wrong (i missed that), it should be `video_params.empty?`. And you must do that check **before** `@video = Video.new(video_params)`. Check updated answer (actually, you won't need to modify `video_params` at all).

Comment: Hey Gerry, thank you so much for helping me. But I am getting this error now: `undefined method empty? for nil:NilClass` . It is referring the `return render 'new' if params[:video].empty?`

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner Sorry, `empty?` is not the right method, change it to `blank?` (i always fall on this).

Comment: Use `return render 'new' if params[:video].present?`

Comment: @MayurShah That will work too, but you will need to change `if` to `unless`.

Comment: @Gerry no need to change `if` to `unless`, it should be `return render 'new' if !params[:video].present?` simple

Comment: Hey guys, I just posted what I did. I totally blanked on adding that small line of code. Thanks a lot for helping ya'll

Comment: @MayurShah Yes, negating `if` will output same result.

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner Good, you found a solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

if anyone needs to know, the way I went around it is, I added a `required: true` to the end of the `file_field` in the form. This way, it doesn't let the user submit the form without choosing a file.

Comment: Thats a good solution too! Just keep in mind that some browers may not support this attribute (older browsers and i'm not sure if Safari supports it at all), so be sure to test properly.